# Неверная выборка при сортировке

Tags: mongodb, php

Mongodb часто возвращает неверные данные при использовании сортировки и лимита, а точнее:

> 1. super_cool  372
> 2. Mew Mew 272
> 3. Колобочек   249
> 4. Flame   239
> 5. Wulfric 226

и

> 1. Sandji  676
> 2. Master  312
> 3. Kartman 287
> 4. Zak 285
> 5. super_cool  253

После 5-10 обновлений страницы результаты совсем другие, но после обновления результат тот, который ожидался изначально. В чем может быть проблема?

Ипользую такой запрос (php):

> $dR =
> $db->dexRatings->find()->limit(5)->sort(Array('dex'
> => -1));

Думал, проблема из-за большой нагрузки. Перенес базу данных на другой сервер - не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find() выдаёт данные в произовльном порядке. Нужно поменять местами сортировку и лимит:

```
$dR = $db->dexRatings->find()->sort(Array('dex' => -1))->limit(5);
```

Другое решение состоит в том, чтобы использовать $orderby в запросе метода find.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

С ним и индексом в теории будет работать быстрее.